# UITabBar selectionIndicatorImage height on iPhone X

Tags: ios, uitabbar, iphone-x

I'm using a `selectionIndicatorImage` for a `UITabBar`, which is 49 points high, like this: `UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "bg-tab-selected")`

Works just fine across all devices:
[image]

Except for the iPhone X:

[image]

I've tried setting the images to be vertically sliced only in the asset catalog, but that doesn't seem to have the desired effect. For some reason it also stretches horizontally? And there is a bit of padding on top.

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had the same issue. I "fixed" it by subtracting the height by 1 pixel, so 48 pixels for the height of the selection image. It seems to be an iPhone X bug.

Comment: Well, that's odd. Would never have thought to try that. Seems to work though, thanks!

Comment: Just great! I wasted 3 hours trying to figure this out. You have my upvote sir!

Comment: @MuhammadUmar please change your image to 48 pixels using Photoshop. If you need code to dynamically change an image to 48 pixels, you can find that in other stackoverflow posts.

Comment: Could be subtracting the height by 1 pixel programmatically

Comment: Tried this, but the same image will not work for both iPhone X and the rest, does the same happens to you?

Comment: Try using a method to resize the image for the iPhone X to 48 px.

Answer (score -1):

Adding 1 point to the top or bottom of your tabBar's selectionIndicatorImage Insets seems to "fix" this for now.

`tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 1, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))`